# what is the vscode shortcut to switch between source control splits

Tags: visual-studio-code

given i'm looking at a changed file, and i have my cursor focused on the left pane, how do i move the focus/cursor to the right pane using either an existing keyboard shortcut or a command?

i want to be able to easily copy stuff from the original version of the file (HEAD) to the changed version of the file.

this is the screen i'm talking about:

[image: vscode showing the "Changes" view of a file, the left pane shows the file before changes, the right pane shows it after the changes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this command:

`View: Focus Other Side in Active Editor`  unbound by default

That will toggle focus back and forth.

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",               // use your preferred keybinding
  "command": "workbench.action.focusOtherSideEditor"
}
```

There are also a `focus first side` and `focus second side` commands available in the Keyboard Shortcuts.